# Monitor Memory contention in Hyper-V guest VM

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Scenario: 
Host: Server 2012R2 Hyper-V w/t 64GB Ram
Guest: Server 2012R2 OS Virtual Machine with 20GB static Ram

Question: How to determine if 20GB Static Ram is enough or too much in the Guest VM?

Commentary: I tried using Veeam One Free edition which is pretty cool but it can't seem to measure Ram performance because the VM is using Static Ram.
Thanks!

Comment: Understood, I tried to clarify this question. Thanks